# Is it possible to seal just patches of new concrete?

Tags: concrete, sealing

I recently had some interior drain tile installed in my basement. During this time I also took it upon myself to fix a few decent sized chips/cracks with a patching compound. The vast majority of my basement is still the original slab.

It's now been about a month and from what I can tell I should be sealing the new concrete to prevent water from wicking up, protect the concrete, etc.
Due to budgetary (and other) reasons, I'd rather not seal all of the old concrete along with the new stuff right now, unless I *really* need to. Is this a reasonable approach, or is it absolutely imperative that it all gets re-sealed at once for some reason?

Answer (score 3):

It isn't critical that all the concrete be sealed at once. It's essentially just a varnish, and while you may see variation in sheen where your applications overlap, it won't affect performance with most products.

When in doubt read the label.